# unable to dpkg cups-pdf

Tags: 12.04, printing, dpkg

By mistakenly i removed cups from my system in terminal by command

```
sudo apt-get remove cups-pdf
sudo apt-get remove cups
```

after that i tried below

```
 sudo dpkg -i cups-pdf_2.5.0-16_amd64.deb 
 Selecting previously unselected package cups-pdf.
 (Reading database ... 167602 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack cups-pdf_2.5.0-16_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking cups-pdf (2.5.0-16) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-pdf:
  cups-pdf depends on cups; however:
   Package cups is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package cups-pdf (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  cups-pdf
```

can you please help me out from this problem.

Comment: @techraf when i tried to dpkg the debian version of cups. its giving dependency eception.

Comment: @techraf and after that i tried sudo apt-get install cups-pdf then i got below error "cups-pdf : Depends: cups but it is not installable
"

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the error message in your question and the error message in your last comment?

Comment: @techraf i know there is no difference, As i am new to ubuntu i am very much confused now. so how i could make it work. can you help?

Comment: I wish I could, but you don't describe your problem. I am not you and I have no clue, if you need an old package and why are you installing it manually.

Comment: The version of `cups-pdf` in the 12.04 repository appears to be 2.6.1-6 so by installing cups-pdf_2.5.0-16 manually (using `dpkg -i`) you have probably made it impossible for `apt-get` to install the repository's version of `cups`

Comment: @s_m Once you wrote that "cups is not installed" the other time that "cups is not installable" - I doubt it's the latter message, but these are your eyes that see and fingers that type.

Answer (score 0):

### Possibility one (assumption: you don't need the old `cups-pdf`):

You removed the packages it with `apt-get remove`, so install them back with `apt-get install`:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

This will install `cups-pdf` with all its dependencies.

---

### Possibility two (assumption: you need the old `cups-pdf`):

The message clearly says that to install `sudo dpkg -i cups-pdf_2.5.0-16_amd64.deb` it requires `cups` package, so install it:

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

then can proceed with:

```
sudo dpkg -i cups-pdf_2.5.0-16_amd64.deb
```

---

### Notice:

In either scenario it is possible (depending on *your* system state) that another dependency problem would arise and you will have to read the message that your system displays you and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .  i tried with  `sudo apt-get install cups`  
its giving below exception `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package cups is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers cups-server-common cups-core-drivers cups-client

E: Package 'cups' has no installation candidate
`